# Static abstract method in Dart

Tags: dart, inheritance, static, abstract-class

I am trying to create a base class that enforces 2 static methods for every class that inherits from it. I've tried to apply multiple solutions but can't find a working one that will allow the inherited classes to be used when generalised as the base class.

This will only enforce all inherited classes to produce the base class

```
abstract class A {
    factory A.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);
}
```

This solution does not work since I can't call fromMap in a static way (`x = b.fromMap()`)

```
abstract class FromMap<T> {
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
    T fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);
}

class B with FromMap<B> {
    B fromMap() ...
}
```

Making the prototypes from the `FromMap<T>` class static is not permitted.

Does Dart have some method to achieve what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Dart does not have any way to force a class to have specific static methods.

Static methods are not inherited, so it doesn't matter which methods the superclass has.

There is also no way to call a static method without knowing the precise class you are calling it on at compile-time. You can't abstract over the type, then call a static function on it.

What you can do instead is to require passing in the function you want, instead of just the type. So, if your code expects a `<T extends A>` and wants to create it using `fromMap`, that function should also ask for the `fromMap` function as an argument as well:

```dart
R parse<R extends A>(R Function(Map) fromMap, something) => 
   .... fromMap(parsedMap) ...;
```